# How do i pass a UICollectionViewCell from App to Framework in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I had a framework containing the UICollectionView and the Json response. I need to design the custom cell in the App and pass it to the Framework. In the framework I should bind the data and load the collection view in the Storyboard.

Comment: which framework you use?

Comment: I use my own framework containing UICollectionView for reusability in my Apps